# Set same width for all input type

Tags: php, css, html

I need your help guys. Is there an easy way how can i set width for all input type in html5 and support it in all browser? I would like all of it to be on the same width but will not affect the width of the checkbox.

```
<input type="text" name="txt1" value=""><br><br>

<input type="date" name="txt1" value=""><br><br>

<select name="slct1" value="">
<option>Select 1</option>
<option>Select 2</option>
<option>Select 3</option></select><br><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="">
```

Thanks guys. Hope you can help me and give me an easy way to do this.

Regards,

Comment: Possibly not duplicated. This question is pointed to how to apply a width to all inputs,without affecting a checkbox input.

Comment: here is my working fiddle -  https://jsfiddle.net/e7qp80fx/
- i used what on the duplicate, but it is affecting the width of the checkbox because it is also included as an input.

Comment: hi. thanks. i solved it just now. i used the code on the duplicate question and made a class for each input so that i will call all classes which are not checkbox type. thanks again. regards.